# Facebook login integration giving NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to integrate facebook login in my android app. It was working fine previously but now giving some error. I don't remember that i have done any changes and the local history is almost same. Here is my code :

```
public class Login extends Activity{

private LoginButton facebookLogin;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private AccessToken accessToken;
private Profile facebookProfile;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            // Set the access token using
            // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
        }
    };

    // If the access token is available already assign it.
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    facebookProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    facebookLogin = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.button_facebookLogin_Login);
    facebookLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    facebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            facebookLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.d("TOP","Object = "+object.toString());
                            try {
                                  //Doing something
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });

  }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    //profileTracker.stopTracking();
   }

  }
```

Logcat :

```
06-18 18:18:09.613    6749-6749/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: braindottech.com.fishid, PID: 6749
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'context' cannot be null
        at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:76)
        at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(Utility.java:594)
        at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:757)
        at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:732)
        at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(AppEventsLogger.java:400)
        at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.logButtonCreated(FacebookButtonBase.java:225)
        at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.onAttachedToWindow(FacebookButtonBase.java:136)
        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.onAttachedToWindow(LoginButton.java:452)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14520)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please help me to find the bug. Thankx in advance!

Comment: Argument 'context' cannot be null... So, where in your code have you used a Context object?

Comment: @cricket_007 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());  this is the only place where i am passing the context.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, the error is being generated within the Facebook library, but try  `Login.this` instead

Comment: @cricket_007 still crashing..

Comment: It is working fine now. But i didn't change anything, I guess the fault was in the Facebook library and is working now after updating the Facebook library.